# jQuery and JavaScript Breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I'm currently running a couple different jQuery libraries on my website, [here](http://soccersurfer.com/)

The rotating banner is from http://codecanyon.net/item/li-jquery-sliderimage-rotator/full_screen_preview/153638

Which has me include these files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/li-slider-animations-1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/li-slider-1.1.min.js"></script>
```

I also am using fancybox (http://fancybox.net/howto) and include the necessary javascript files.

I got everything working fine until I tried to use this plugin, (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy)

I could not get that tipsy plugin to work without removing these javascript files from my header

```
    <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I realize I'm probably doing something wrong by including all of these different jquery libraries, but how can I go about having everything work at the same time even though they appear to be using different files.

I included my site URL so you can check the source file to see if there is something I should fix and what I should do so I can add the correct tipsy files.

Thanks

Comment: add only single jQuery src on the top of all. And remove another versions of jQuery script tags.

Comment: Why are you including two (or more) different versions of jQuery?

Comment: Because the other plugins weren't working on a single jQuery script tag. I assumed they only ran on the one that was specified on their website. How can I condense this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple versions of the jQuery library on the same page.

How would a script know what library to use?

Only include 1 jQuery script and find updated / other jQuery plugins if they are incompatible.

Or write the needed functionality yourself.